# How can I combine two newly created columns and also create a column for the division of both

Tags: python, pandas

I have the first column:

```
df_weight = df2.groupby(['Genre']).agg(total = ('weighted score', 'sum')).reset_index()
```

|  | Genre | total_weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Action and Adventure | 1000.0 |
| 1 | Classic and cult TV | 500.0 |

and the second column:

```
df_TotalShow = df2.groupby(['Genre']).agg(total = ('No. of shows', 'sum')).reset_index()
```

|  | Genre | total_shows |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Action and Adventure | 200.0 |
| 1 | Classic and cult TV | 150.0 |

I want to combine the two and make something similar below but I am unsure of what the code should look like.

|  | Genre | total_weight | total_shows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Action and Adventure | 1000.0 | 200.0 |
| 1 | Classic and cult TV | 500.0 | 150.0 |

Next, I want to create another column with the division of total_weight / total_shows.
So far, I tried

```
df = df_weight['total'].div(df_TotalShow['total'])
```

but this gives me a new series. Is there a way where this could be another column by itself with the final product looking something like

|  | Genre | total_weight | total_shows | Avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Action and Adventure | 1000.0 | 200.0 | 5.0 |
| 1 | Classic and cult TV | 500.0 | 150.0 | 3.33 |

Comment: No need to separately calculate and merge them.  you can have multiple aggregations `df2.groupby(['Genre']).agg(total_weight= ('weighted score', 'sum'), total_shows=('No. of shows', 'sum'))`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```py
df = df2.groupby(['Genre']).agg({'no. of shows': 'sum', 'weighted score': : 'sum'}).reset_index()

df['division']=df.col1/df.col2
```

replace the name of your columns. You must perform one time aggregation and grouping for this problem not 2 times